# How do I list rows from a SQL table into my jquery script?

Tags: php, sql, jquery

I'm creating a pricing array jQuery and for this project the amount of different products I need is going to be +200 so the easiest option I could research would be listing from a SQL table.

This is what I have so far:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            /*** CONSTANTS ***/
            var KEY = 0;
            var VALUE = 1;
            /*** DEFINE DATA SETS ***/
            var POINTS = [ ["250", 46.5 ], ["500", 53.5], ["1000", 67], ["2500", 107.5], ["5000", 175], ["10000", 310] ];
            var SHIPPING_COSTS = [ ["Pickup", 0], ["Next Day Delivery", 30], ["Same Day Print/Same Day Delivery", 65] ];

            for (var i = 0; i < POINTS.length; i++) {
                $("#quantity").append("<option value='" + POINTS[i][VALUE] + "'>" + POINTS[i][KEY] + "</option>");
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < SHIPPING_COSTS.length; i++) {
                $("#shipping").append("<option value='" + SHIPPING_COSTS[i][VALUE] + "'>" + SHIPPING_COSTS[i][KEY] + "</option>");
            }

            $("select.autoUpdatePrice, input.autoUpdatePrice").bind("mousedown click change", function(event) {
                Calculate();
            });
            Calculate();    
        });


    function Calculate() {
        var net = parseFloat($("#quantity").val());
        /* Calculate the magical # by adding the form fields*/
        var designFee = $("#abcDesignFee").attr("checked") ? $("#abcDesignFee").val() : 0.0;
        var proofFee = $("#abcProofFee").attr("checked") ? $("#abcProofFee").val() : 0.0;
        var MyPrice;
        MyPrice = parseFloat( parseFloat(proofFee) + parseFloat(designFee) + net + parseFloat($("#shipping").val()));
        $("#DumpHere").html("Your Price: $" + formatNumber(MyPrice));
        $("#abcName").val($("#quantity").find(":selected").text() + " " + ProductNamePlural);
        $("#abcPrice").val(MyPrice);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a PHP file and read the data from SQL into an array. Print that array after [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Then use [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) on document ready to fetch it and process it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, any chance you could maybe help me in the right direction for printing sql data into an array? I've looked, and am lost.

Comment: @David When you use mysql_fetch_array in a loop, you get it in an array form. Create a new array and push the data required into it with array_push or [] operator. If you start a new question regarding this, you will get better help.

Comment: I wound up getting the json_encode to work, thank you, now I am working on getting it into my javascript! Thank you again!